# AS3 cacheAsBitmap confusion

Tags: actionscript-3

My goal was to have low resolution circles (very pixelated).  I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm trying to understand how cacheAsBitmap works.  When I use a sprite sheet that I have drawn very very small, and then scale the bitmap up, it looks great (very blocky, pixelated, smoothing turned off).  Fine.  But when I draw a circle programatically very small (say radius of 4), and then cache it, and then scale it up, it is pixelated, but very much a full, round circle.  I take it that somehow the player isn't actually caching it as a bitmap until it is rendered on the screen. Even when I don't do the scale up until the swf is fully loaded and running, I still just get big circles that are perfectly round (but pixelated).  Is there a way to cache something programatically that will then scale up the way my imported bitmaps do?

the code I tried looks basically like this:

```
        for (var i: int = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            var size: Number = 8;
            var item: RunnerMassObj = new RunnerMassObj();
            item.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x0,0,true);
            item.graphics.beginFill(0xFF8844 + i * 10);
            if (i < 10) {
                item.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0,size);
            } else {
                item.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
            }
            item.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(item);
            item.x = Math.random() * 1000 + 50;
            item.y = Math.random() * 1000;
            item._bottom.y = size;

            // here I cache it as a bitmap.
            item.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            allMassObj.push(item);
        }
```

and then in my engineTick code I have this:

```
    for(var i:int = 0; i < allMassObj.length; i++)
    {
        // and here I scale it up, expecting the pixels to stay pixelated.
        // has the circle somehow maintained its vector shape?
        allMassObj[i].scaleX = 10;
        allMassObj[i].scaleY = 10;
    }
```

and instead of the big pixels on the left, I get the tiny "true to screen" pixels on the right:

[image]

Any insights will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you convert your **item** into a `BitmapData` then you could disable smooth:

```
item = new BitmapData(instance.width * scale, instance.height * scale, true, 0x0);

item.draw(instance, m, null, null, null, false); // final false disables smoothing
```

(Do not tryied but I think it's worth to have a look)

Best.

Edit: additionally: try to investigate something near color depth of your bitmap. As you know, if you can convert your bitmap to 1 or 2 bit colors, then resizing it, probably you will get a hard pixelated image as you wish.

Comment: +1 for giving me the faith to move in this direction.  I thought this was just for anti-aliasing.  I just finally got it to work, minus a few needed tweeks, but I'm getting the chunky pixels.  I'll edit your answer with the full working code in a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Neal. I'm glad to see that you found your way. God bless.

Answer (score 2):

> But when I draw a circle programatically very small (say radius of 4), and then cache it, and then scale it up, it is pixelated, but very much a full, round circle.

The thing is that it's just *cached* as a bitmap. It doesn't behave like one. [The documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap) is pretty clear on this one:

> After you set the `cacheAsBitmap` property to `true`, **the rendering does not change**

The point of `cacheAsBitmap` is to improve rendering performance for complex vector data that doesn't change:

> If set to `true`, Flash runtimes cache an internal bitmap representation of the display object. This caching can increase performance for display objects that contain complex vector content.

It basically "bakes" the vector geometry into pixels behind the scenes, so that it doesn't have to do the calculations to display it again and again.

When the `DisplayObject` is transformed, the cache is updated. That's why you never see a pixelated version of your circle.

Comment: Thanks for the added clarity! Much appreciated!